# Fetching custom fields using spring data jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-boot-jpa

I have relationship between 4 tables, A has B, C, D.

B having many to many relationship with A and C having onetomany with B and D has one-to-one with A.

Now how to fetch only a1, b1, c2, d1&d2 columns using spring data jpa.

Comment: Please provide more details about what you've already tried. And please improve your formatting. How about a diagram of the relationships to make it clearer to understand?

Comment: I tried adding diagram but it's failed while uploading